# Error when i use layout tag in databinding in xml android project

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.util.KaptBaseError: Exception while annotation processing
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't make a guess for databinding.ActivityStartPageBindingImpl
```

Comment: Check your XML, you probably have an errore somewhere

Comment: i found something , problem is my package name has capital letter like com.ExamPle  ,  that's why my databinding is not working , so have any solution regarding this?

Comment: Why you think it's the reason? Regarding package name you can simply rename it

Comment: yes i rename it but my application is on playstore com.ExamPle  and now i have do com.example ,  now myquestion is can i update my application by this new package name or not.

Comment: You can update your package name but make sure that "applicationId" in build.gradle remains same as playstore id (com.ExamPle).

Comment: solved thanks @HBB20

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue after upgrading the Kotlin version to 1.4 in my project. Downgrading to `ext.kotlin_version` to `'1.3.50'` fixed the issue. Apparently the kapt plugin in gradle 4.1.1 doesn't fully support databinding yet in this kotlin version.

Answer (score 0):

Had same error and error because of package name is capital latter, So after make is small its working

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Android Studio version 4.1.1. I fixed this problem by updating the Android Studio to version 2020.3.1. Just try to update Android Studio.